# Android: What is the best way to go about implementing a board for a game?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm starting work on a game, with the majority of all actions taking place on the 4x3 board in the middle of the screen.

As far as Android is concerned, what would be the best way to go about implementing said board? I was considering GridView, but that seems to be more focused on being a list of items than an actual board. I need to know the coordinates of pieces on the board, and not every space will always be filled. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Comment: I've ended up just going with my own Custom view, because even TableLayout didn't quite meet my needs. Thanks anyway!